# Is there a Google Play app that can be pushed to a device with a broken screen to retrieve data without user interaction?

Tags: google-play-store, data-recovery, broken-screen

I'm at my last resort with a OnePlus 6 with a broken screen, with the only remaining option being to order a replacement screen to get back into the phone to retrieve the data. Before I go that route, I wanted to check if there isn't a Google Play app I could push down to it to retrieve my data.

- Though I had enabled adb at one point and authorized my computer, it seems to have been reset/cleared authorizations through a system update, and doesn't present over adb when connected to USB
- The digitizer doesn't seem to work either to hit a button / stab in the dark at user input
- USB OTG support is off at boot, and can only be turned on for a limited time in the settings, which prevents keyboard/mouse input
- The bootloader is locked, so if I unlock it to flash TWRP, my data will be wiped
- OnePlus Repair refuses to not wipe my data if I send it in for a screen repair
- Dropbox is installed and would sync the pictures, however I turned off syncing when my dropbox was filled and I don't think I can 'push' settings changes down to the device

However, it boots just fine and connects to my wifi at home. Are there any Play apps that I could push to the device that would run without user input and allow me to retrieve data from the phone? I mostly just want my pictures and videos, but ideally would want to review the entire file system.

Does anything like this exist? Even just opening a read only ftp service would work for me, but I suspect that I can't just push down any .apk using the Google push option, and that due to the potential for abuse many aren't allowed into the store.

If I'm wrong... well I could start writing an .apk to do this I suppose, unless someone has already jumped this hurdle before.

EDIT

Alternatively - anything I could push from Google Play that would enable adb (USB or WiFi) and authorize anything connected without user input would also get me up and running.

Comment: The only thing It goes through my mind is to install an emulator, who will screen your phone to your pc… and then using the PC you transfer the dana to the PC.

Comment: Are there any Google Play Store apps that I could push that would do this without any user input on the device?

Comment: Not trying to sponsor, but I think the app's name was Vysor.
And yes, you need to install the app using ADB.

Comment: @FiN If I had adb working, I could just get my files :) I'm looking for something I can deploy down to the phone through the Google Play store 'deploy to phone' feature.